# Suspension and reduced suspension

Tags: algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

It is clear to me that
for a space $X$ , the suspension $SX$ is the quotient of
$X × I$ obtained by collapsing $X×\{0\}$ to one point and $X × \{1\}$ to another point. The motivating example is $X = S^n$ , when $SX = S^{n+1}$
with the two ‘suspension points’ at the north and south poles of
$S^{n+1}$ , the points $(0, ··· , 0, ±1).$ One can regard $SX$ as a double cone on $X$.

But my problem is to imagine  in a form of a picture this **reduced suspension**:

$ΣX = SX/(\{x_0\}× I)$.  How does this look like ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take the example of $X := S^1$, then $SX$ is a 2-sphere.  And $\Sigma X$ is obtained from $SX$ by contracting a vertical line connecting north and south poles.

The idea is that your original basepoint in $S^1$ is now an entire interval in $SX$, and you sometimes want a canonical basepoint.

Comment: In the example we have $SX$, $\Sigma X$, $S^2$ are topologically equivalent, right? Is this true in general, I mean that  $SX$, $\Sigma X$, are topologically equivalent?

Comment: @Matija Contracting an arc, as in going from $SX$ to $\Sigma X$, in reasonably nice spaces, gives you a homotopy equivalence, but not necessarily a homeomorphism. For example, if $X$ is just a single point, then $SX$ is an arc, and $\Sigma X$ is a single point.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Are the two disks in $X\times I$ at the ends of $I$, $0$ and $1$, contracted to a point too as in $SX$ for the case of $X=S^1$ ? Or just the vertical line $\{x_0\}\times I$ is contracted ?

Comment: Ah, of course, thanks!

Comment: @Matija Good, but my original definition says that only the vertcial line is contracted, look at this: $ΣX = SX/(\{x_0\}× I)$. So which case it really is ?

Comment: @user122424 The two ends $X\times\{0\}$ and  $X\times\{1\}$ are contracted to points in forming $SX$. My comment was about the subsequent contraction of an arc in going from $SX$ to $\Sigma X$. So in the final result $\Sigma X$. the union of both ends and that arc has become just one point.